# Permanent fix for Lightroom autoplay problem?

Tags: lightroom

I've had an ongoing problem on my Windows 10 system with Lightroom CC not opening via autoplay when I insert a memory card. I managed to fix the issue but every time a Lightroom update is installed autoplay breaks again for the same reason.

The problem (and fix) is that the registry key

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers\Lightroom6AutoPlayHandler

has the data in quotes, which seems to break autoplay.

[image]

When I remove the quotes

[image]

autoplay works fine, lightroom opens to the import dialog as expected...

Is this a known problem, or have I discovered something unique to my setup? Anyone know how to fix things so I don't have to do a registry edit every few weeks?

Comment: Have you tried the Adobe help forums? What did you find?

Comment: Has this problem been resolved? If not, consider contacting Adobe.